# SAPUI5 VizFrame false data is picked

Tags: sapui5

I have a sapui5 project with a graph made by vizframe. The graph has two dimensions (Date and Condition) and one measure
(Rest Value). The Rest Value is taken from invoices. But on one Date there can be multiple invoices of course. When this happens the vizframe graph automatically picks the first value he can find for this date, I think. Example: Date is 01.01.2023, there are four invoices for this date with the Rest Values: 1, 2, 3, 4. Because my model I get from the backend via Odata is ordered descending for Rest Value, the first value for this date is 4. Problem is I really have to display the lowest value for every date so i want the 1 not the 4. I hope my problem is understandable.

My graph is of vizType "timeseries_line". The Date is of course on the uid timeAxis, Dimension is uid color, and Rest Value on valueAxis. The sapui5 version im using is 1.108.0. The Vizframe is created in a xml view but the data binding is done in the controller with a FlattenedDataset and feeds.

I have been reading the sapui5 API Reference and asking ChatGPT questions but didnt get any smarter.
I hope someone can help me, thanks very much.

I did a lot of research but I could not find anything similar.

Comment: Can't you change the order in your OData implementation to fit your needs?

Comment: No, the data has to be ordered this way :(